# What happens to the messages being processed on functions running when we disable the function?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-function-app

We are working with Azure functions, which are triggered on every message in the service bus queue. We are trying to solve a problem whereby we need to disable a function on the function app processing messages, dynamically, so that it does not process messages any further and we do not lose any message in the process as well.

We can disable the functions via multiple ways, referring to [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function) but the problem remains the same. **Unable to figure out what happens to the functions already spawned when trying to disable the same**.

Since the function is service bus triggered there is always a possibility that the function is processing a message and we disable the same, does it get processed, any sorts of cancellation is raised, it just dies out with an exception?

It would be great someone could direct me to some documentation or something. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Service Bus triggered function will already have a lock on the message that's being processed. If Function is terminated and the message was not completed or disposition, the lock will expire and the message will reappear on the queue. That's because of the Functions runtime [receives a message in `PeekLock` mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#peeklock-behavior).

One factor to consider is the queue's `MaxDeliveryCount`. If a function is terminated upon the last processing attempt, the message will be dead-lettered as all processing attempts have been exhausted. That's a standard Azure Service Bus behaviour.